# Easiest way to install Windows 7 Remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows Vista box in the corner, but no spare keyboard/monitor. What's the easiest way for me to install it remotely? OPK?

Comment: Honestly? I think the easiest would be to temporarily attach a mouse, keyboard & monitor.

Comment: You know what, you're right. Please put this as an answer, and I'll vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a keyboard and monitor to the computer temporarily. Even just borrowing one from another computer for the hour or so required to install an OS should be sufficient. Once the OS is installed and configured for headless/remote operation, the keyboard and mouse and monitor can be removed back to their original system.